Performance_Testing_using_jmeter for workflow running on temporal
I need to do end to end performance testing of an application having workflow running on temporal and it triggers series of api endpoints. can we do it using JMeter? has anyone done it before using any other tool?
I tried using jmeter but don't understand how to do end to end performance testing using JMeter where api are triggered automatically as part of workflow. If not JMeter then any other tool?


You can trigger the workflow using i.e. Temporal CLI from OS Process Sampler or using JSR223 Sampler with Groovy language and Temporal Java Client
Put another OS Process Sampler or JSR223 Sampler which will wait for the workflow completion under the While Controller
Put everything under Transaction Controller to measure end-to-end workflow processing time

